# Loading MANY orders in Magento - allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: magento

I am getting 3000+ entity ids from sales_flat_order and have to get the items of each of the corresponding orders. At the moment I am using this code to load any of the 3000+ orders and their items:

```
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIdInForEach)->getAllItems();
```

This is not a good idea as I am running into memory problems. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to load many items would be using the `fetchItem` method for the collection.

```
$collection = $orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
while(($order = $collection->fetchItem())) {
    //Do your thing here without loading all orders 
    //that match the above collection filters.

    //Get current order items
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
}
```

The `fetchitem` method will fetch only one record from the database and not all of the objects which would cause memory execution problems. I hope this helps clear up things for you.